# Which JavaScript to include in minified file (UMD, CommonJS, Browser)

Tags: javascript, module

I'm adding the `angular-multi-step-form` library to my Web project.

The distribution folder contains three folders: `browser` with both a minified and unminified script, `umd` with the same, and `commonjs` with an index, directives and services folder.

Which file(s) do I include in my `index.html`  tags while developing, and more importantly, which file do I include in my gulpfile for `uglify`?

(The app in question is intended to be responsive and usable on all platforms. As I understand it, UMD relates to mobile device browsers, but I want to fully support both desktop and mobile browsers in the same app, so I'm not sure which file I'd include even between those two...)

The documentation `for angular-multi-step-form` doesn't say anything about this, it simply gives you a link to the Github source and then the JavaScript code to actually use it, but nothing about which script file to actually load. So there must be something that is assumed that I am not familiar with. (I'm relatively new to JavaScript/front-end web coding, but I have not yet seen this pattern in any library I have used so far.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UMD has nothing to do with mobile (it stands for Universal Module Definition). The choice between the three depends on whether you're using a module bundler, such as Webpack or Browserify.

If you're just concatenating your scripts together and accessing them as global variables, then you need to use the browser version - since you have minification in your Gulp config, I'd opt to use the unminified version, as re-minifying code tends to make UglifyJS go horrendously slow.

If you're using a bundler (i.e. your code has `require("...")` or `import { ... } from "..."` in it), then you need to import either the CommonJS version or the UMD version. I'm almost certain based on your question that this isn't what you're doing, though.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!